# s3 client.uploadFile() hangs with no error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My credentials work successfully with AWS cli to upload s3 files, the credentials are associated with an admin user on a bucket which is a static site. **Update: Download works as expected**. For some reason the node 's3' package fails, but no error is displayed, it just logs:

```
progress 0 4561 4561
progress 0 4561 4561
...
unable to upload: RequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
    at Request.extractError (/Users/../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:700:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
```

And I'm not sure what the problem would be? Any insights? The code is below, it's taken directly from the s3 package https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

```
// RUNNING NODE 11.0 (due to un-updated dependencies in s3 or aws-sdk it must be under 11.15)
const { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey } = require('./tools/AWS.json')
const s3 = require('s3')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const awsS3Client = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: 'us-east-2',
})

const client = s3.createClient({
  s3Client: awsS3Client,
})
const liveBucket = 'my-bucket'

const params = {
  localFile: 'out/404.html',
  s3Params: {
    Bucket: liveBucket,
    Key: '404.html',
  },
}

const uploader = client.uploadFile(params)
uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  // never runs ...
  console.error('unable to upload:', err.stack)
})
uploader.on('progress', function() {
  // runs like 5 times before failing after a long wait
  console.log('progress', uploader.progressMd5Amount, uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal)
})
uploader.on('end', function() {
  // never runs ...
  console.log('done uploading')
})
```

Permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show your S3 bucket permissions

Comment: SMELLS like a proxy issue

Comment: @aminits I just added it, sorry for the late reply! Also, no proxy exists that I know of.

Comment: I may be naive but why the `const s3 = require('s3')` and `const client = s3.createClient({` rather than using the aws-sdk directly for the upload?

Comment: @ptierno s3 is the wrapper package that is widely used. I'm going to next attempt to use the aws-sdk directly, although I shouldn't have to :/ but it's next on my debugging checklist

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your upload hangs because of a bucket permissions issue. Please try to add the following permissions to your bucket:

- s3:PutObject
- s3:PutObjectTagging
- s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
- s3:ListMultipartUploadParts

Comment: I wish this worked, but it doesn't. I have all my ACLs turned off to allow public access if this matters.

Comment: im not sure where in the error you determined this was a bucket policy/permissions issue when it clearly states `RequestTimeout`